# Can I request scripts for use in a Spotify app?

Tags: http, node.js, socket.io, spotify

I'm trying to use socket.io in my spotify app and the get request for [domain]/socket.io/socket.io.js keeps getting canceled. I've added the domain to the manifest and everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try restarting Spotify. Your app's `manifest.json` file is loaded when you first view your app, and cached until you quit, even if you modify it.

#### Note: How external resource permissions work

In order to request external resources, your application needs to specify each domain it plans to connect to in its `manifest.json` file.

Add a line like this:

```
{
  // ...
  "RequiredPermissions": [ "http://*.spotify.com", "http://spotify.com", "http://test.example.com" ]
  // ...
}
```

For the full details check out [the Permissions section of the Spotify Apps API Guide](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/#permissions).

Comment: Have you required scripts this way?

Comment: Yes. Have you restarted Spotify? Manifests are cached for the duration.

Comment: That was it, didn't know that the manifests were cached that long. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. I've clarified my answer. Sorry for the lack of reading comprehension the first time. :)

Answer (score 1):

I can add that when you use socket.io it will try to initialize Flash to check if flash is available so if you find a white box in Spotify (only in Windows), remove the swbobjects initialization in the socket.io.js on the node server.